# Can I avoid the Abel partial summation technique and instead prove uniform convergence in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Edit:  I am attempting to use summation by parts...and will revise the below proof, as the R.H.S. says nothing more than what the L.H.S. already gives.

The problem statement is:

For 2 sequences of functions ${a_n(x)}$, ${b_n(x)}$ on an interval $I$, suppose that $b_n(x)→0$ uniformly in $I$, $∑_1^{\infty}|b_n(x)−b_{n−1}(x)$| converges uniformly in $I$, and $∣∑_0^na_k(x)∣<M$ in $I$ for all $n$. Show that $∑a_n(x)b_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $I$.

My proof, using summation by parts:

To be less wordy, I won't show my derivation of the summation by parts formula, although it is the same spirit as robjohn's derivation on a link in MSE.

Since $b_n$ $\to 0$ uniformly On $I$, then for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N_1$ s.t. $n>N_1$ implies that $|b_n(x)|<\epsilon$.

Also, since $\sum |b_{n+1}(x) - b_n(x)|$ converges uniformly on $I$, then for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N_2$ such that $\sum_{N_2+1}^{\infty} |b_{n+1}(x) - b_n(x)|<\epsilon$, for all $x$ $\in$ $I$, by the Cauchy criterion for convergence.

Now, let $N=max(N_1, N_2)$.

We have that, by summation by parts,

$$\sum_{n=N+1}^{m}a_n(x)bn(x) = (A_mb_m-A_{N}b_{N+1})-\sum_{n=N+1}^{m}An[b_{n+1}-b_n]$$

$$\implies |\sum_{n=N+1}^{m}a_n(x)bn(x)\large| = |(A_mb_m-A_{N}b_{N+1})-\sum_{n=N+1}^{m}An[b_{n+1}-b_n]|$$

$$\le |(A_mb_m| +|A_{N}b_{N+1}|+|\sum_{n=N+1}^{m}An[b_{n+1}-b_n]|$$

$$=M\epsilon + M\epsilon + M\epsilon$$
$$=3M\epsilon$$

since the partial sums of $a_n$ are bounded, i.e. $|A_n|<M$ for all $n$, using triangle inequality, and finally using the Cauchy criterion for the uniform convergence of the telescoping series of $b_n$.

Now, taking $m \to \infty$, the first estimate on the R.H.S. goes to zero, and we are left with the estimate

$$|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}a_n(x)bn(x)\large| \le M\epsilon + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}An[b_{n+1}-b_n]|$$

$$\le M\epsilon +  M\epsilon$$

$$=2M\epsilon$$

But the inequality must hold for all $\epsilon>0$, and so we conclude that $\sum a_n(x)b_n(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion for convergence, uniformly on $I$, and so the series must converge uniformly on $I$, since the space $R$ is a complete metric space.

End of proof.

My (erroneous) work, attempting to use the dominated convergence theorem:

We start with the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)[b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x)]= \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^m a_n(x)\int_0^1(b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x))dt$$

$$=\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^m \int_0^1a_n(x)(b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x))dt$$

$$=\lim_{m \to \infty}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^m a_n(x)(b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x))dt$$

$$=\int_0^1\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^m a_n(x)(b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x))dt$$

$$=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x)(b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x))dt$$

note that I took the limit inside of the integration, since here both the uniform convergence theorem or dominated convergence theorem would allow the switch.

Now I want to claim that the integrand is convergent, by the assumptions of uniform convergence of the telescoping series of $b_n$, coupled with the fact that the $a_n$ are bounded for all $n$.  Then the R.H.S. is finite.

And so the L.H.S. is finite and breaking out the L.H.S. gives two convergent series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)[b_n(x)-b_{n-1}(x)] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)b_n(x) -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)b_{n-1}(x)<\infty $$

And so we have that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x)b_n(x)<\infty$$

as required.

Is this ok?

Any hints or comments are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: why are you integrating in $t$?

Comment: This does not show uniform convergence.

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I initially had applied the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but wasn't getting anywhere with it.  So, I then tried to go for an approach that uses the dominated convergence theorem.  I integrated in t to keep the RHS equal to the LHS.  Now I'm thinking I must use summation by parts and have ran out of options - I was reluctant to use it since I am not familiar with it.  Do you possibly see a way to solve this problem without summation by parts?  Thanks so much ...

Comment: I don't really. The given conditions almost scream for summation by parts.  However, I can give an answer that uses summation by parts to get the uniform convergence, but that seems contrary to the point of the question.

Comment: I had been trying for awhile to derive the summation by parts formula, so that I don't have to rely on memorization, and I was stuck for a bit and realized my mistake, when I read  your derivations on another question on MSE -- thanks so much, @robjohn.  I will proceed with this problem statement now and see what I can put together -- and then compare with hermes' answer below ...

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I put together a proof using summation my proofs -- what do you think of it? I tried to keep it as succinct as possible.  Thanks...

Comment: I will now read hermes' work and compare, but I would love to hear your thoughts, too, if you have some time to comment.  Thanks, @robjohn,

Comment: ...was it necessary for me to take m to infinity and give a second estimate?  Or was my first estimate, for m, n > N=max($N_1, N_2$) enough to conclude that the original series is uniformly Cauchy?  Thanks @robjohn,

Comment: Hi @robjohn, fyi, I have posted my proof as a new question on MSE - thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Abel partial summation to get the estimate of Cauchy sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(x)b_n(x)$.

Let $A_n(x)=\sum_{k=m}^n a_k(x)$. So for all $n,m$ and any $x\in I$, there is
$$
|A_n(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} a_k(x)\right|<2M\tag1
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^n a_k(x)b_k(x)&=\sum_{k=m}^n (A_k(x)-A_{k-1}(x))b_k(x)
\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^n A_k(x)b_k(x) -\sum_{k=m}^n A_{k-1}(x)b_k(x)
\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} A_k(x)(b_k(x)-b_{k+1}(x))+A_n(x)b_n(x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
Note that $A_{m−1}(x)=0$. 
By Cauchy criterian, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $N$ such that for $n,m>N$ and any $x\in I$, there is
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |b_k(x)-b_{k+1}(x)|<\epsilon\quad\text{and }\quad |b_n(x)|<\epsilon\tag3
$$

So for all $n,m>N$ and any $x\in I$, by $(1), (2), (3)$ there is
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=m}^n a_k(x)b_k(x)\right|&\leqslant\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |A_k(x)||b_k(x)-b_{k+1}(x)|+|A_n(x)b_n(x)|
\\
&<2M\sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |b_k(x)-b_{k+1}(x)|+2M\:\epsilon 
\\
&<4M\epsilon
\end{align}
So by Cauchy Criterion, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k(x)b_k(x)$ converges uniformly in $I$.

Comment: Hi @hermes, are you referring to something called "summation by parts"?

Comment: Hi @hermes -- what do you think of my revised proof?  I just edited my question.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @hermes, first, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and then using the assumption that the partial sums of $a_n$ are bounded (for all $n$) ...

Comment: ah, you're absolutely right ... thanks @hermes, I will now revisit the Abel partial summation formula.  It seems a bit technical, so I was trying to avoid it ...

Comment: Hi @hermes, can you see my revised proof that I just posted?  I am using the swapping of summation and integration, using uniform / dominated convergence theorems to take the limit inside of the integration, and then concluding from there :-).  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @hermes, the R.H.S. of my latest proof would converge absolutely, as well as uniformly, by assumption.  So I think it is pretty clear that the R.H.S. is finite.  And so, using the same quantifier "N", of course, we achieve uniform convergence on the L.H.S.  But we can break the L.H.S. out into two series, of which one of them is the desired series.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: What is integral? There is no integral in the sum.

Comment: It's exactly equal ... it's integration over [0,1], it's a common technique to rewrite a number in this way ... especially to utilize the swapping of summation with integration ... @hermes

Comment: and the integrand is treated as a constant -- no dependence on the integration variable , which is "t" ... @hermes

Comment: Do you like it @hermes :-)  I think I'm either correct .... or ... very close now ...

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @hermes :-)

Comment: Ok got it -- will read it after I try one last time, with summation by parts @hermes

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is can Abel Summation be avoided. I wrote a similar answer yesterday, but didn't post it for this very reason. Evidently, that this has helped Lebron James a lot, but a new question should really have been posted.

Comment: @Lebron James  tried several proofs avoiding Abel Summation, but all failed (read the previous comments). So I show him the right proof must use Abel Summation.

Comment: Thanks so much @hermes -- especially for sticking with me, while I tried several different methods, which all failed.  That in itself taught me a lot, in addition to my finally using the summation by parts technique :-)  Hope to hear from you soon!  Have a great night! :-)